# Next.js Link not resolving to the correct folder at design time in WebStorm

Tags: next.js, hyperlink, webstorm, next.js13

I have a Next.js project using Turborepo in WebStorm where the Next.js Link components show the error `Cannot resolve file 'xxxxx'` even when the path exists.

I've created a sample project [here on GitHub](https://github.com/WillCalderwood/next-link-unresolved)

I'm guessing there's something wrong with my setup, but I can't figure out what the issue is.

[image]